# Is there an easy way to customize the entities generated by Spring Roo/DBRE?

Tags: java, database, spring-roo

I'm looking for an easy way to customize the entities that the database reverse engineering (DBRE) add-on for Spring Roo generates.

If, for example, I want all my entities to implement `Serializable`, or to have the default annotation `@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = false)` instead of `true`, I'd like to be able to define that prior to running DBRE (instead of adding/editing manually afterwards, which just seems to run contrary to the Roo way of doing things).